# Is it an issue if i use $("#ElementId").val() on a non exsisting element ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following script inside my asp.net mvc web application:-

```
 $("body").on('click', '#DCSort', function () {



        $.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url: Path,

            data: { searchTerm: $("#HsearchTerm").val(), page: "1", sort: $("#HDCSortPam").val(), pagesize: $("#FilterSize").val(), activefilter: $("#FilterActive").val() },

        success: successFunc,
        error: errorFunc
    });

    function successFunc(data, status) {     
        $(TargetTable).html(data);
        $(DCProgressSort).hide();

    }

    function errorFunc() {
        alert('error');
    }
})
```

now this is a general script used all over my web application , so on some web pages they do not have all the passed parameters included in the passed data;
`$("#HsearchTerm").val()`, `$("#HDCSortPam").val()`,`$("#FilterSize").val()`,  `$("#FilterActive").val()`

**now when i first deploy the script i though that the script will raise errors if it try to use the .val() on non-existing element** , such as "FilterActive is undefined" .. but seems that javascript will ignore the element  if it can not find it .. so can anyone adivce if this is an acceptable behavior to leave the script as is , so even if the element does not exists it will be ignored by the script without having to worry about it ...

Comment: jQuery is smart enough to handle empty stuff. It doesn't return undefined. It simply ignores the code. You don't need to check.

Comment: @PraveenKumar you mean it will ignore the non-exsisting element not all the elements ? is this correct ?

Comment: Well, technically, you should be using that method because **1-** jQuery doesn't throw errors when the selectors returns null **2-** Avoid caching

Comment: `$(selector)` *always* returns a new jQuery object, representing a (possibly empty) collection of elements. However, the *result interactions* have to considered when asking "will this break". For example, it may be required the final value is a non-empty string.

Comment: @johnG Yes. Right...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery will handle it pretty well. For example, consider the selector `#HsearchTerm`. Assuming there is no element matching the selector, `$("#HsearchTerm")` will be an empty jQuery object and `$("#HsearchTerm").val()` will be `undefined` (no error though).

`$.ajax` will ignore keys in the `data` object that have `undefined` for their value, so the result will be that `searchTerm` will be left out of the query string for the ajax request.

It's not safe to assume that you can always skip checking for existence though. In general if you try to access a property of `undefined` JavaScript will throw an error, so something like `$("#HsearchTerm").val().length` would throw an error. A common way to check if the selector had any matches is to check the [length](https://api.jquery.com/length/) of the collection: `$("#HsearchTerm").length` will be `0` if there was no match.

Comment: so it is better to check if ($("#HsearchTerm").length != 0) before accessing its val() ? is this correct ?

Comment: @johnG It depends on your usages of the value. If you are okay with it being `undefined` then you don't need to check. That seems fine for your case above. You just need to be aware that accessing another property, like `$("#HsearchTerm").val().length` will throw an error if `$("#HsearchTerm").val()` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Could use `.is()` , `AND` `&&` , `OR` `||` , return empty string or `false` if element does not exist in `DOM`

```
var check = function(el) {  return el.is("*") && el.val() || "" };
```

---

```
data: { searchTerm: check($("#HsearchTerm"))
  , page: "1"
  , sort: check($("#HDCSortPam"))
  , pagesize: check($("#FilterSize"))
  , activefilter: check($("#FilterActive"))
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not try it and see? Most browsers support runtime javascript in their URL bars and the majority of sites will have already linked jQuery:

```
javascript: var x=$("#some-non-existient-element").val();alert("Type: " + typeof x + " Val: " + x);

// The search bar of StackOverflow:
javascript: var x=$("#search input").val();alert("Type: " + typeof x + " Val: " + x);
```

Comment: Did you read the question? And nowadays no browser allow to run JavaScript without a bookmark.

Comment: Yes, I read the question. Instead of giving a stock yes/no/inaccurate answer I decided to point out that it's *very* easy to check these things using runtime js. The development console will flag any exceptions. Also, you can still run javascript in the URL bar of chrome and firefox. They just make you type in the `javascript:` part.

Comment: Good but it is not clear that elements are not there by mistake or intentionally. It might be case of conditional HTML elements and believe me now you can not run JavaScript in address bar! The days are over of JS hack :D

Comment: I'm running firefox 43.0.2 and can run the example in this answer with no issues?